# CakePHP 3 & jsGrid using AJAX - AJAX callbacks successful, but loading from and updating/deleting data to MySQL fails

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, ajax, cakephp

I'm attempting to pass data via AJAX to my Controller's add function within a jsGrid script, however currently no data passes through. The AJAX callbacks do work however (I've included console.logs for successes and failures and they show up).

Below is my InstrumentController's add function:

```
public function add()
    {
        $instrument = $this->Instruments->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $instrument = $this->Instruments->patchEntity($instrument, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Instruments->save($instrument)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The instrument has been saved.'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The instrument could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $resources = $this->Instruments->Resources->find('all')->toArray();
        $this->set(compact('instrument', 'resources'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['instrument']);
    }
```

Below is the jsGrid script with the AJAX callbacks (View is based in the Resources table):

```
<script>
   var instruments = [
       {Name: "", Id: 0},
       {Name: "Drum Kit", Id: 1},
       {Name: "Violin", Id: 2},                        
   ];

   $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
       width: "100%",
       height: "400px",

       inserting: true,
       editing: true,
       sorting: true,
       paging: true,

       controller: {
           loadData: function (filter) {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?= $basepath ?>/instruments.json",
                    data: filter
               });
           },
           insertItem: function (item) {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= $basepath ?>/instruments/add.json",
                    data: item,
                    success: function(){
                         console.log("Data was successfully inserted.");
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                         console.log("Data could not be inserted.");
                    },
                    complete: function(data){
                         console.log("Callback was successful.");
                    }
               });
           },
           updateItem: function (item) {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= $basepath ?>/instruments/edit.json",
                    data: item,
                    success: function(){
                         console.log("Data was successfully updated.");
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                         console.log("Data could not be updated.");
                    },
                    complete: function(data){
                         console.log("Callback was successful.");
                    }
               });
           },
           insertItem: function (item) {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= $basepath ?>/instruments/delete.json",
                    data: item,
                    success: function(){
                         console.log("Data was successfully deleted.");
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                         console.log("Data could not be deleted.");
                    },
                    complete: function(data){
                         console.log("Callback was successful.");
                    }
               });
           }  
       },
       fields: [
                    {
                         name: "instrument",
                         title: "Instrument",
                         type: "select",
                         items: instruments,
                         valueField: "Name",
                         textField: "Name",
                         validate: "required",
                         width: 175
                    },
                    {name: "comment", title: "Comment", type: "text", width: 150},
                    {name: "resource_id", type: "text", width: 150},
                    {type: "control"}
               ]
       });
</script>
```

`$host` = http://localhost
`$basepath` = /project

Eg. for InsertItem's POST url: `http://localhost/project/instruments/add.json`

In my MySQL database, my Instruments table has the following attributes:

- ID (int, primary key, auto incremental, not null)
- Resource_ID (foreign key related to Resources table) (int, not null)
- Instrument (varchar, not null)
- Comment (text, default = null)
- created (datetime)
- modified (datetime)

I did a check on the URL that appears in console when doing a POST using [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), and it seems to be valid JSON.

No errors appear in the console when I attempt to do an AJAX post.

**Update:** Re cake baking the Views fixed the issue for Adding, although it has not solved the loadData issue.

Comment: Why are you doing an Ajax post inside an Ajax post?

Comment: There was another Stack Overflow post that was similar in some ways that said a 2nd one needed to be done. I was following that. In any case, I've fixed my issue (at least for insertItem/the add Function). Now I'm just trying to get the data to be loaded when the page loads.

Comment: It's redundant, to insert only a single call is needed. Try logging or pruning the result of $instrument->errors() after the save call, it should tell you why it refused to save

Comment: The solution for the add function was: Re cake baking the Views for the add function (probably missing some newer form inputs), and also my resource_id foreign key was being sent in as a string instead of an integer. But it hasn't solved my loadData issue - refreshing the page wipes the jsGrid clean. I've also included my updateItem and deleteItem functions as well, as they're also not working - it's not a View issue this time, as I cake baked the Edit view as well (Delete doesn't have a View).